# How to substitute multiple space with a single space in Vim

Tags: vim

I have the following lines. I'd like to replace multiple spaces with a single space in vim. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

```
Percent                      I4-15
b Percent and Fractions                   16-19
c Percent and Decimals                    20
d EstimatingPercents                     21
```

Comment: I suggest you look up [regular expressions](http://vimregex.com/).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do it with a vim regex.

:%s# \+# #g

Comment: Or use "`\s`" instead of " " to match any kind of whitespace.

Comment: Thanks it worked. What is #, \+# etc? Can you explain it please?

Comment: The basic construct of the command is s#search#replace#.  Sometimes you see it as s///.  The % before the s tells the regex to work on all lines in the vim buffer, not just the current.  The space followed by \+ matches one or more spaces.  The trailing g tells the regex to match multiple times in a single line.

Comment: If you are bothered by replacing a single space with a single space (wasted effort) then, instead of ` \+` (one or more spaces) you can use ` \{2,\}` (two or more spaces) or `__\+` (a space followed by one or more spaces--I am using "_" instead of " " because HTML refuses to display two consecutive spaces).

Comment: For single line: `:s/\s\+/ /g`